# Why callback function after not($(this)) repeats multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this

I have made a callback function which is meant to fire up after

```
$('.menuIco').not($(this)).fadeOut()
```

but instead of 1 callback I have 9 callbacks (probably because of 10-1=9 elements due to `not($(this))`).

Why? and how to prevent it?

I'm using a workaround with a variable, but it doesn't seem to me too professional.

```
var loaded = false;

$('.menuIco').not($(this)).fadeOut(function() { // hide all icons but one
    if(loaded==false) {
        loaded = true;

        $('.menuIco p').addClass("icoCaptionOff");
        $(menuIco).animate({top: "20", left: "-100"}, "fast", function() {
            LoadContent($(menuIco).attr('id'));

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML code too please. Ta

Comment: you are going to have to include the encapsulating javascript so we can see what `$(this)` refers to

Comment: Also you can just use `.not(this)` instead of `.not($(this))`

Comment: What's called 9 times? The anonymous function bellow `fadeOut()` or `LoadContent()`?

Comment: fyi, `.not(this)` is sufficient. no need to wrap it in a jquery element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to execute a callback after the animation of all elements are completed

> The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is
>   resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection,
>   queued or not, have ended.
>
> By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved
>   when all animations of the selected elements have completed.

```
$('.menuIco').not(this).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
    $('.menuIco p').addClass("icoCaptionOff");
    $(menuIco).animate({
        top: "20",
        left: "-100"
    }, "fast", function () {
        LoadContent($(menuIco).attr('id'));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have multiple elements with class `.menuIco`. So in your callback you should use `$(this)` instead of selecting `$('.menuIco p')` again.

```
var loaded = false;

$('.menuIco').not($(this)).fadeOut(function() { // hide all icons but one
    var $this = $(this);

    if(loaded==false) {
        loaded = true;

        $this.find('p').addClass("icoCaptionOff");
        $this.animate({top: "20", left: "-100"}, "fast", function() {
            LoadContent($this.attr('id'));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` and `then` deferred handlers to execute a function when another is completed:

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more
>   objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Code:

```
$('.menuIco').click(function () {
    $.when($('.menuIco').not(this).fadeOut()).then(function () {
        console.log('foo')
    })
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/hvm79/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to apply the callback on `$(this)` and not on every `.menuIco` in every callback function.

```
$('.menuIco').not(this).fadeOut(function() { // hide all icons but one

        $(this).find('p').addClass("icoCaptionOff");

        $(this).animate({top: "20", left: "-100"}, "fast", function() {
            LoadContent($(this).attr('id'));
        });

});
```